# Android TouchEvent: how to calculate which coordinate the will ball be reached

Tags: java, android, user-interface, math, physics

I developing an application like Facebook's Chat Head

so far I achieved drag and flick the ball, to reverse side of ball position

i.e. ball in screen left 50%, flick right then move to right edge, from right flick left then move to left edge

[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 2]

my current code shown below:

```
Point initialPos = new Point();
PointF initialTouch = new PointF();
Point delta = new Point();

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            initialPos.set(mWindowParams.x, mWindowParams.y);
            initialTouch.set(event.getRawX(), event.getRawY());
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            int releaseX = (int)event.getRawX();
            int releaseY = (int)event.getRawY();

            travel[0] = mWindowParams.x;
            travel[1] = mWindowParams.y;
            if (Math.abs(delta.x) < (Dimension.screenX * 0.15) && Math.abs(delta.y) > 100) {
                travel[2] = 0;
                travel[3] = Math.min(Math.max(0, releaseY), bottomEdge);
            } else {
                /*double rad = Math.atan2(initialTouch.y - releaseY, initialTouch.x - releaseY);
                double degree = (rad * 180 / Math.PI + 180) % 360;*/
                double slope = (releaseY - initialTouch.y) / (releaseX - initialTouch.x);
                double straightLineEquation = initialPos.y - initialPos.x * slope;

                if (initialPos.x < Dimension.screenX / 2) {
                    // flick right
                    int destY = (int) (Dimension.screenX * slope + straightLineEquation);
                    travel[2] = Dimension.screenX - mBall.getWidth();
                    travel[3] = Math.min(Math.max(0, destY), bottomEdge);
                } else {
                    // flick left
                    travel[2] = 0;
                    travel[3] = Math.min(Math.max(0, (int) straightLineEquation), bottomEdge);
                }
            }
            moveBallToPos(travel);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            delta.set((int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouch.x), (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouch.y));
            mWindowParams.x = initialPos.x + delta.x;
            mWindowParams.y = initialPos.y + delta.y;
            mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mBall, mWindowParams);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I using Slope Equation and Straight-line Equation, but doesnt handle all cases..

1. Try to flick to another side, but turn back at middle (see Pic 4)
2. Vertical flick (currently only works in sometimes, my guess is only y = 0 will works, maybe need to adjust sensitive? If you don't understand then you can try flick FB messenger chat head vertically)

[image: Pic 3]
[image: Pic 4]

Please give me some idea how to do that, my mathematics is sucks, thanks a lot!